# JQuery / JS / HTML - Sort dynamic list based on user selected input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, sorting

I'm working on creating a recommendations list. The user will add a recommendation and select its type from dropdown list (pub/restaurant, etc).

**I want to add the option to sort the list by type (which is input from the dropdown).**
I'm not sure how to do it, any advice will be highly appreciated.

The methods I used might not be the most efficient and the sort might be complexed because of it, so I would be happy to hear any general note you might have as well.

Thanks in advance!

html Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Must See in NYC</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" name="recommendation" value="Type your recommendation here">
        <select id="recommendation_Type">
            <option class="Type" value="Pub" data-sort="1">Pub</option>
            <option class="Type" value="Restaurant" data-sort="2">Restaurant</option>
            <option class="Type" value="Dessert">Dessert</option>
            <option class="Type" value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
        </select>
        <button class="Add">Add!</button><br/>
    </div>

    <button class="typeSort">Sort by Type</button><br/>


    <ul class="recommendations"></ul>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var removeButton="<button class=Remove></button>";
    var ratingStar="<button class=Rating></button>"
    var ratingStars=ratingStar+ratingStar+ratingStar+ratingStar+ratingStar;
    var addToNewReco="&nbsp"+"&nbsp"+"&nbsp"+ratingStars+"&nbsp"+"&nbsp"+removeButton;


    $('input').focus(function() {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid black", "border-radius", "10px"); 
    });

    $('button.Add').click(function() {
        var toAdd = $("input[name=recommendation]").val();
        var recType = $("#recommendation_Type").val(); // The value of the selected option
        if (recType=="Pub") {
          $('.recommendations').append('<li>'+"&nbsp"+"&nbsp"+toAdd+addToNewReco+"</li>");
        } else if(recType=="Entertainment") {
            $('.recommendations').append('<li>'+"&nbsp"+"&nbsp"+toAdd+addToNewReco+"</li>");
        } else if(recType=="Restaurant"){
            $('.recommendations').append('<li>'+"&nbsp"+"&nbsp"+toAdd+addToNewReco+"</li>");
        } else if(recType=="Dessert"){
            $('.recommendations').append('<li>'+"&nbsp"+"&nbsp"+toAdd+addToNewReco+"</li>");
        };
        $('input').val('Type your recommendation here');
    });

    $('ul').on('click','button.Remove', function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    });

    $('ul').on('click','button.Rating', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('Rated');
        $(this).prevAll().toggleClass('Rated');
    });

});
```

Comment: Your code is a bit broken. It adds the recommendation but also an unwanted element. Please fix it first. Look [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S8M7DMeoNWqGvl7nCMbr), edit it and share new code and/or fixed plunker.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thank you very much for your comment. I removed part of the code that I thought I already removed, sorry about that. I'm not sure what is the problem at the moment, in Chrome it works but in the Plunker the entity is duplicated. Link to Plunkr [link] https://plnkr.co/edit/tcciYtjvKziC9O4LHbdh?p=preview